# CFMessagePort is not receiving the messages

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am looking at example https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mac/NSPortExample/

I am trying to recreate the Obj-C code into c# but I am not having any success.

Below is my simple version of the Obj-C , can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, please.

```
static class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NSApplication.Init();
            var localPost = CFMessagePort.CreateLocalPort("com.example.app.port.server", HandleCFMessagePortCallBack, CFAllocator.Default);
            CFRunLoopSource runSource = localPost.CreateRunLoopSource();
            CFRunLoop.Current.AddSource(runSource, (NSString)string.Empty);
            while(true){}
        }
        static NSData HandleCFMessagePortCallBack(int type, NSData data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Data:{0}",data);
            return new NSData();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the `kCFRunLoopCommonModes` via `CFRunLoop.ModeCommon`:

```
static CFMessagePort localPort;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NSApplication.Init();
    localPort = CFMessagePort.CreateLocalPort("com.example.app.port.server", (int type, NSData data) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data:{0}", data);
        return new NSData();
    });
    var runLoopSource = localPort.CreateRunLoopSource();
    CFRunLoop.Current.AddSource(runLoopSource, CFRunLoop.ModeCommon);
    NSApplication.Main(args);
}
```

Note: Also you should not execute a spin loop, you will block the port's run loop. You can put it onto another thread and perform a wait on the thread... Personally when creating "Cocca cmd line" apps, I still use the Window/`ViewController`, just setting it to hidden.

Comment: Thank you SusjiHangover, the missing CFRunLoop.ModeCommon was the solution. Wish I could give more than one up's!